# Could not run "bash build/build.sh" command in Windows PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, build

Currently I'm working on testing a github repository and I'm following the github's README.md that requires me to run "bash build/build.sh" command line to build environment. But I somehow could not make the command run in my PowerShell. Windows PowerShell keeps showing "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install ' to install.

Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Bash/Service/CreateInstance/GetDefaultDistro/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND"

I have installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview from Microsoft Store but I still could not run the "bash build/build.sh" command.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved. I have solve it by following this youtube video.
https://youtu.be/mDmpnkjETpw

Basically you have to check two boxes in the "Turn Windows features on or off" before start trying out the Linux command.

1. Virtual Machine Platform
2. Windows Subsystem for Linux

Thanks for viewing.